# ruby typical eql? and == implementations

Tags: ruby, equality, idioms

I've been reading about the differences between `eql?` and `==` in ruby, and I understand that `==` compares the values while `eql?` compares the value and the type

According to the ruby docs:

*For objects of class Object, eql? is synonymous with ==. Subclasses normally continue this tradition, but there are exceptions.*

It does not seem like the behavior specified in the docs is automatically inherited, but rather this is just a suggestion of how to implement these methods. Does this also imply that if you override either `==` or `eql?` then you should override both?

In the class `Person` below, is this the typical way of overridding `eql?` and `==`, where the less restrictive `==` just delegates to the more restrictive `eql?` (it would seem backwards to have `eql?` delegate to `==` if `==` was only implemented to compare values and not types).

```
class Person

  def initialize(name) 
    @name = name
  end

  def eql?(other)
    other.instance_of?(self.class) && @name == other.name
  end

  def ==(other)
    self.eql?(other)
  end

protected
    attr_reader :name

end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I get the confusion now, what the docs meant by [aliasing](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-alias_method) the eql? and == methods are implemented like this:

```
class Test
  def foo
    "foo"
  end
  alias_method :bar, :foo
end

baz = Test.new
baz.foo #=> foo
baz.bar #=> foo

#override method bar
class Test
  def bar
    "bbq!"
  end
end

baz = Test.new
baz.foo #=> foo
baz.bar #=> bbq!
```

So that's why when you override ==, it doesn't affect eql? even though they're 'synonymous'. So in your case, it should be:

```
class Person
  #...
  def ==(other)
    other.instance_of?(self.class) && @name == other.name
  end
  alias_method :eql?, :==
  #...
end
```

Comment: Isn't it equal? you shouldn't override? The docs give the specific example of how Numeric implements == and eql? differently

Comment: You're right, equal? is the one that should not be overwritten. I updated my answer.

Comment: @Vincent, if == and eql? are synonymous, I would think that overriding one would cause them both to have the same behavior then. I tried overriding eql? and not ==, and then I tried overriding == and not eql?, and the behavior was not the same, which is why I'm confused by the documentation that they are synonymous.

Comment: I also found this in the ruby source code for object.c  Subclasses normally continue this tradition by aliasing <code>eql?</code> to their overridden <code>==</code>, so it doesn't sound like this happens automatically. https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/object.c

Comment: @Vincent, that's how I ended up doing the aliasing, but what I'm still confused about what is the "typical" ruby behavior? Is it common to see the aliasing of eql? and == like this?

Comment: @Jeff, if you browse the Ruby src, you can see how eql? and == are implemented. In Numeric, for instance you can see this [code](http://pastie.org/4166349). I used the gem [Pry](http://pry.github.com/) for browsing the Ruby src code. :)

Comment: @Vincent, I understand what you're saying, I'm just trying to understand the typical ruby idioms and whether it's typical to be doing this, that's all.

Comment: It's typical for all the subclasses of Object. What I meant by viewing the source is when you look at eql and == on [Object](http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/source/object.c#104), they have the same code but when you look at Numeric or [String](http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/source/string.c#2305) they are defined differently.